# Jquery toastr onHidden function

Tags: jquery, toastr

I am using jquery toastr.  So far everything is great. I can display and close toasts fine.
I want to be able to identify each toast uniquely. And use that unique identifier in the onHidden function.   Has anyone done this before? Is the better option to call a jquery on close event for the toastr class or div surrounding the closed toast?

```
    var mes = 'My name is Inigo Montoya.<input type="hidden" id="announcementId" value="1"/>' +
       '<input type="hidden" id="userId" value="'+ userid +'"/> ';

    var mes1 = 'Princess Bride<input type="hidden" id="announcementId2" value="2"/>'+
       '<input type="hidden" id="userId1" value="'+ userid +'"/> ';

    var mes2 = 'Man in Black<input type="hidden" id="announcementId2" value="3"/>'+
       '<input type="hidden" id="userId2" value="'+ userid +'"/> ';

   var mes3 = 'Inconcivable!<input type="hidden" id="announcementId3" value="4"/>'+
       '<input type="hidden" id="userId3" value="'+ userid +'"/> ';

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "0",
  "extendedTimeOut": "0",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};

toastr.options.onHidden = function(item) { 
//GET UNIQUE TOAST ID'S HERE
        var val = 1;//$this.find("#announcemntId").val();
        alert("CLOSED " + item); 
}

toastr.error(mes, "First Toast");
toastr.error(mes1, "Second Toast");
toastr.error(mes2, "Third Toast");
toastr.error(mes3, "Fourth Toast");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody runs across this later here was my solution.
Loaded toasts from json.  Each toast is inside its own unique div (info, error, warning, succuess) and each has a class assigned to it.  I assigned hidden attributes in each message in the toast with values I needed.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/announcements/getannouncements/userid/' + userid,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var mes = '<input type="hidden" id="userId" value="' + userid + '"/>' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="announcementId" value="' + val.id + '"/>' +
                'Client:  ' + val.client + '</br>' + val.announcement;
            var title = val.title;
            toastr.error(mes, title); //info, success, warning, error
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Could not get announcments");
    }
});
```

Since closing the toast happens when you click on the div I could capture the div class that was clicked on, find the announcement and user id and preform my logic

```
//class could be warning, error, info, success : we only use error
$(".toast-error").live('click', function () {
    var userId = $(this).find("#userId").val();
    var announcementId = $(this).find("#announcementId").val();
    var url = '/announcements/acknowledge/userid/' + userId + '/announceid/' + announcementId;
    // ajax call to the controller to write the timestamp of the user clicking the toast announcement
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                alert("Successfully acknowledged");
            }
            else {
                alert("Data error");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the third parmeter which is the options override

```
toastr.error('Some error', 'Error', { onHidden: function() {
         console.log('Error toast hidden.')
}});
```

or modify the global onHidden

```
var onHiddenToast = function () { 
        console.log("onHidden");
}
toastr.options.onHidden = onHiddenToast;
```

also you can get the toast simply by referencing it

```
var myToast = toastr.info("Some info");
//do what you want with myToast
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Will consider all those on future uses!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand these answers, so i am adding my own. I used jquery to create an onclose function, (when someone clicks the toast-close button) like this -

```
$('.toast-close-button').click(function() {
*someCodeHere 
});
```