# Javascript Audio in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I've been trying to play an audio linked to a toast notification . I'm currently using `toastr.js` .

```
toastr.warning(eventData.type);
self.eventAudio[eventData.id] = {};
self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio = new Audio();
self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.src = './images/someaudio.mp3';
self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.loop = true;
self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.play();
```

`eventData` has a unique Id in id key : `eventData.id`.

what i wanted was for a particular toastr notification , audio is played and for `toastr.options.onHidden`, i've bound a function with the contents :

```
 var self = this;
toastr.options.onHidden = function() {
  self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.pause();
}
toastr.options.onclose = function() {
  self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.pause();
}
toastr.options.onCloseClick = function() {
  self.eventAudio[eventData.id].audio.pause();
}
```

The issue i'm facing is that , the audio is always in loop and never paused , not even after the toast notification is hidden .This issue is when the toast notification has more than one instance ,like i have 2 or more notifications.

What am i doing wrong ? 
Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use `() => {` instead of `function() {`, then `this` just works and you don't need that `self` hack.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult because the `toastr.js` library doesn't pass any identifiable event information to the onHidden/onClose/onCloseClick callbacks. If you look at the source code, it's calling the same options.onHidden() function for all toast events.

```
if (options.onHidden && response.state !== 'hidden') {
    options.onHidden();
}
```

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/master/toastr.js

Right now what you're doing is overwriting the callback function for every new event. (If your last `event.id` is abc, every time any toast is closed it will try to pause the audio associated with abc.)

The easiest (and probably most user friendly) way to do this is to create a single Audio element that gets restarted every time a new toast appears.

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = './audio/test.mp3';
audio.play();

toastr.options.onHidden = function() {
  audio.pause();
}
toastr.options.onclose = function() {
  audio.pause();
}
toastr.options.onCloseClick = function() {
  audio.pause();
}
```

If you need it to keep playing continuously until all toasts are closed, you could have a counter that pauses the audio when there are no more active toasts

Comment: Thank you for the reply .i used jquery to access a particular toast , i'll update the answer on how i managed to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I used Jquery to access the uniqueId in the `eventData.id` .

`toastr.warning()` , `toastr.success()` ,`toastr.error()`, `toastr.info()` takes input: `message` , `title` for notification .

```
var message = '<input type="hidden" id="eventId" value="'+ eventData.id +'"/>';
toastr.warning(message,eventData.type);
$('.toast-warning').on('mouseleave',function(){
   var eventDataId = $(this).find('#eventId').val();
   self.eventAudio[eventDataId].pause();
   self.eventAudio[eventDataId].src ='';
});
```

I bound the `onHidden()` ,`onclose()` , `onCloseclick()` with :

```
$('.toast-warning').trigger('mouseleave');
```

Since the `<input>` has its type as hidden , it was not visible in the toast notification , and i accessed the element easily using:
`$(this).find()` .

Used this to reach the answer: [Jquery toastr onHidden function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817500/jquery-toastr-onhidden-function)